# Visual Studio C++ std::istream::read Fails with File Open

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to write a classifier for the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) in C++ using Visual Studio, but the std::istream::read function I'm using to read one of the image files is failing part way through reading the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

uint8_t* decodeImage() {
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("train-images.idx3-ubyte", std::ifstream::in);

    std::cout << "Is open: " << fin.is_open() << std::endl << std::endl;

    char* fourBytes = (char*)malloc(4);
    uint32_t acc = 0;

    fin.read(fourBytes, 4);

    acc = (uint8_t)fourBytes[0];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[1];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[2];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[3];

    std::cout << acc << std::endl << std::endl;

    fin.read(fourBytes, 4);

    acc = (uint8_t)fourBytes[0];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[1];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[2];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[3];

    std::cout << acc << std::endl << std::endl;

    fin.read(fourBytes, 4);

    acc = (uint8_t)fourBytes[0];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[1];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[2];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[3];

    std::cout << acc << std::endl << std::endl;

    fin.read(fourBytes, 4);

    acc = (uint8_t)fourBytes[0];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[1];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[2];
    acc = (acc << 8) + (uint8_t)fourBytes[3];

    std::cout << acc << std::endl << std::endl;

    free(fourBytes);

    char buff;

    uint8_t* ret = (uint8_t*)malloc(28 * 28);

    for (int i = 0; i < 28 * 28; ++i) {
        fin.read(&buff, 1);
        while (fin.fail() || fin.bad()) {
            std::cout << "IO error, shutting down." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Good: " << fin.good() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Bad: " << fin.bad() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Good: " << fin.good() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Fail: " << fin.fail() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "EOF: " << fin.eof() << std::endl;
        
            exit(-1);
        }

        ret[i] = (uint8_t)buff;
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    decodeImage();

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get when running the program is the following:

```
Is open: 1

2051

60000

28

28

IO error, shutting down.
Good: 0
Bad: 0
Good: 0
Fail: 1
EOF: 1

C:\Users\jleona15\source\repos\MNIST\Debug\MNIST.exe (process 11060) exited with code -1.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

So, the file is clearly being opened successfully, because it reads the magic number, number of images in the set, and the height and width of the image before the reads start failing. This happens when executing via "Debug>Start Without Debugging", but it also happens when running the executable in the Debug folder through the command line. I am pretty sure this is a Visual Studio issue, because executing the same code in a Code::Blocks project yields success:

```
Is open: 1

2051

60000

28

28


Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.034 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Any advice from the Visual Studio aficionados? I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio to no avail.

Comment: Try `fin.open("train-images.idx3-ubyte", std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);` As written, the file is opened in text mode, and there's probably an ASCII 26 byte in there that is interpreted as end-of-file.

Comment: Much appreciated, works perfectly now!

Comment: Unrelated: Any reason for the `char* fourBytes = (char*)malloc(4);`? Far as I can tell a plain-old stack allocated `char fourBytes [4];` should do the job with less fuss.

Comment: Force of habit from a C class I took, you are correct though, I'll swap that out in future.

Comment: Concerning `char* fourBytes = (char*)malloc(4);`, I would have given the same advice if I had it seen in a C program...

Comment: Not force of habit because it was C, force of habit because of our professor preferring that we use malloc to get used to how it works.

Comment: Then again, I'm not defending it, I already acknowledged ```char fourBytes [4];``` is the better way of doing it.

Comment: Not critics - rather observation: For a variety of strange / unidiomatic / unusual pieces of code (complained in comments) I read the excuse of the OP "The professor wanted us to make it like this." Assuming that this was not a misunderstood requirement... Professors are teaching at schools / universities. They may have some pedagogical intentions in mind. However, they are usually not responsible to develop or maintain a big software in a team over years. So, take these things they insist on with a grain of salt... ;-)